# junk chars after server migration

Tags: php, sql-server, .htaccess, joomla

i recently moved my joomla website after it was moved to new server i saw lots of junk chars like Â and many other how to fix it .

i tried below code in .htaccess

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .utf8
AddCharset windows-1252 .html
```

i also tried below in index.php

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
 ini_set('mssql.charset', 'windows-1252')
```

but it did not worked , please guide way to fix it.

Comment: where did you found those junks? can you be a little more descriptive?

Comment: in page displaying data from db

Comment: So there are 2 possibilities, either data in db is corrupted, or your pages did pickup some tags during migration with possibility of db having these characters is high. Can you tell where is this data?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redo the export/import process of the data - it seems that you have lost the right encoding either with the export or the import of the data.

This is tricky to do if you're using phpMyAdmin to export/import the data from one server to another. Better use `mysqldump` to export the data from the older the server:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p [db-name] -r [db-file.sql]
```

...and then copy the data to the new server using `scp`, and then finally importing the data using the `mysql` command:

```
mysql -u [db-user] -p [db-pass] < [db-file.sql]
```